# What is the underlying type of the items in a collection of type MatchCollection?

Tags: c#, .net

I assumed it's of type `Match`, but that's not correct because I'm getting the error

> Cannot implicitely convert type type 'System.Collections.IEnumerator'
>   to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator

on the line

```
IEnumerator<Match> friendsULsEnumerator = friendsULs.GetEnumerator();
```

where `friendsULs` is of type `MatchCollection`. I tried doing

```
var friendsULsEnumerator = friendsULs.GetEnumerator();
```

and hovering over the `var` to see if Visual Studio told me the specific type, but it only showed `IEnumerable`. :(

To broaden my question to my greater problem, I'm trying to get the values Donald Trump, Hillary Clinton, etc. out of a `string`

```
<h2>Friends</h2><ul><li>Donald Trump</li><li>Hillary Clinton</li>...</ul>
```

which occurs only once in a larger string. So what I have is

```
                MatchCollection friendsULs = DataReader._fregx.Matches(sr.ReadToEnd());
                if ( friendsULs.Count != 1 ) throw new Exception(String.Format("Couldn't find exactly one piece of HTML matching {0}", 
                                                                                DataReader._fregx.ToString()));
                IEnumerator<Match> friendsULsEnumerator = friendsULs.GetEnumerator();
                if ( friendsULsEnumerator.MoveNext() )  { } // because MoveNext() returns a bool, this useless block is necessary
                MatchCollection friendsLIs = DataReader._lregx.Matches(friendsULsEnumerator.Current.ToString());
```

but maybe you can suggest a more compact and elegant way of doing that entirely.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection(v=vs.110).aspx for matchcollectoin (it has example in the bottom). Where are you getting this html from and is it xhtml ? Check this question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c) and obvious answer - HTML Agility Pack

Comment: @vittore The example on that page does not answer my question

Comment: Perhaps this one will shed some light http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Steve In my situation the format of the HTML of the files I'm reading is consistent enought for me to employ regular expression searches without any potential problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you're calling, `GetEnumerator` is a method defined by the **non-generic** `IEnumerable` interface. It returns a non-generic `IEnumerator`, which is not the same as the `IEnumerator<T>`. So to answer your question: `MatchCollection` is indeed a collection of `Match` objects, but as it does not implement the generic `IEnumerable<Match>` interface, you need to "cast" manually. The `OfType` method does exactly this: converting a non-generic `IEnumerable` collection to a generic one of the type specified.

That said, `GetEnumerator` is a method you would seldomly need in "canonical C#". From your code example, it seems that you just need to get the first `Match` in the collection. This is much easier and more elegant with LINQ, for example with the `Single` operator:

```
Match match = friendsULs.OfType<Match>().Single();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily iterate over the matches using:

```
foreach(Match match in friendsULs)
   // do whatever with match here
```

This is the NET 1.0 pattern of iterating enumerables, since there were no generics back then.

Comment: I don't want to iterate over them. I just want the first and only one of them.

Comment: @AbolishtheIRS then use `Regex.Match` instead of `Regex.Matches`

Comment: I'm confused as hell then, why not just do `friendULs[0]`? It has the proper `Match` type.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying type of a `MatchCollection` is indeed a `Match`. `GetEnumerator()` returns a simple `IEnumerator` (i.e. the version pre-dating generics, where all the elements are an object and you need to cast them yourself.)

Typically you would process all the items in a loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < friendULs.Count; i++)
{
    Match thisMatch = friendULs[i];
    ...
}
```

You can convert a `MatchCollection` to an `IEnumerable<Match>` with `friendsULs.OfType<Match>()`.

Comment: That's good to know, but I'm not sure it asks my question, which is: What is the `<T>` in the type `IEnumerable<T>` returned by `GetEnumerator()` called on a `MatchCollection` object?

Comment: It's just an `IEnumerable` not an `IEnumerable<T>`. I've updated my answer to clarify.